# How to remove quotes from json null when concatenating into a string?

Tags: json, string, null

I can't get rid of the single quote from around null here:

```
const obj = {"ItemData": {
        "ItemId": 4335549,
        "CustID": null,
        "dateCreated": "2021-02-01 07:50:51.1670000",
        "amount": 10.99         
    }
}

let x= "'" + obj.ItemData.ItemId + "|''" + obj.ItemData.CustID + "''|" + obj.ItemData.dateCreated + 
"|" + obj.ItemData.amount + "'"
regx = /'null'/ig
console.log(x.replaceAll(regx, null))
```

I get this:

```
'4335549|'null'|2021-02-01 07:50:51.1670000|10.99'
```

I want this:

```
'4335549|null|2021-02-01 07:50:51.1670000|10.99'
```

Also tried standard replace, same result.

How to remove the quotes from around null?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
regx = /''null''/ig
console.log(x.replaceAll(regx, null));
```

or you can try more generic

```
let x="";
Object.keys(obj.ItemData).forEach((key) => { x += "|" + obj.ItemData[key] });
x= "'" + x.substring(1) + "'";
```

Comment: How silly of me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to only insert the quotes when the value is not null

```
let x= "'" + obj.ItemData.ItemId + "|" +
    ((obj.ItemData.CustID === null) ? "null" : ("'" + obj.ItemData.CustID + "'")) + "|" + obj.ItemData.dateCreated + "|" + obj.ItemData.amount + "'"
```

Comment: I need the quote there for when the string is not null. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add null handling logic, which should be faster than the regex replacement.